# Service Stack Licensing

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I just noticed this commit: 6dbc2fae4dac29c891a67d09aa36ea7426a48051

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/6dbc2fae4dac29c891a67d09aa36ea7426a48051

What implications will this have on people currently using ServiceStack for free?

If the ServiceStack project is indeed looking to move to licensed product, when is it likely to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several posts on the [community](https://plus.google.com/communities/112445368900682590445) page that explain the [licensing](https://plus.google.com/110206964695196648971/posts/TAr55EPCGuF) of v3 and v4 and timelines. 
An alpha ([oct 14](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/NxHUpV1sg1d), [oct 21](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/KoUyRbmYoPJ)) of v4 is already released if you want to take a look at the new bits. A beta is targeting the end of November 2013.